# Turret bullet follows the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently, my turret bullet follows my player. How to stop it and make it only move forward of the last position of my player? Here is my code currently:

TurretBullet Class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TurretBullet : MonoBehaviour {
    private Transform target;
    public float speed = 70f;
    public void Seek(Transform _target) {
        target = _target;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (target == null) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        float distanceThisFrame = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;


        if(dir.magnitude <= distanceThisFrame) {
            HitTarget();
            return;
        }

        transform.Translate(dir.normalized * distanceThisFrame, Space.World);
    }

    void HitTarget() {
        Debug.Log("Player Hit!");
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

I saw somewhere that I need to use `Vector3.forward` I tried experimenting but I couldn't make it work. How do I properly implement it?

Turret Class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Turret : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform target;

    [Header("Attributes")]
    public float range = 15f;
    public float fireRate = 1f;
    private float fireCountdown = 0f;

    [Header("Unity Setup Fields")]
    string playerTag = "Player";

    public Transform partToRotate;

    public float turnSpeed = 10f;

    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public Transform firePoint;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating("UpdateTarget", 0f, 0.5f);
    }

    void UpdateTarget() {
        GameObject[] players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(playerTag);
        float shortestDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
        GameObject nearestPlayer = null;

        foreach(GameObject player in players) {
            float distanceToPlayer = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position);

            if(distanceToPlayer < shortestDistance) {
                shortestDistance = distanceToPlayer;
                nearestPlayer = player;
            }
            else {
                target = null;
            }
        }

        if(nearestPlayer != null && shortestDistance <= range) {
            target = nearestPlayer.transform;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(target == null)
            return;

        Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
        Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(partToRotate.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed).eulerAngles;
        partToRotate.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, rotation.y, 0f);


        if(fireCountdown <= 0f) {
            Shoot();
            fireCountdown = 1f / fireRate;
        }

        fireCountdown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    void Shoot() {
        GameObject bulletGO = (GameObject)Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        TurretBullet bullet = bulletGO.GetComponent<TurretBullet>();

        if (bullet != null)
        bullet.Seek(target);
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected() {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, range);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The bullet follows the player because you compare the bullet position with the *current* player position every time:

```
Vector3 dir = target.position - transform.position;
```

`Transform` is a reference type, so your `target` field gets the same object instead of its copy.

You should copy the original position instead. To make a copy, assign `target.position` - `Vector3` is `struct`, hence, is a value type:

```
private Vector3 position;

public void Seek(Transform _target)
{
    position = _target.position;
}
```

More info: [Value Type and Reference Type](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type)

Comment: I used that to get my target position in different class. Sorry I didn't clear things up. I'll post the other class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that?
TurretBullet Class:

```
private bool aimed = false;
public void Seek(Transform _target) {
if(!aimed){
    target = _target;
    aimed = true;
}

}
```